# REACT this.props.history.push does not redirect

Tags: reactjs

I've got this search method where I want to redirect the user after searching. The issue is that it does not do anything and I don't know why. this.props.history IS defined but the "location" property of the object "history" does not seem to change accordingly to what i put in the parameters of the push method ('./connexion') ... The search method IS binded and I use `export default withRouter(SearchBar);` to access the history via props

```
 search(event) {
    if (this.state.location === null) {
        this.setState({ geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input-alert' });
    } else if (this.state.subjects.length === 0) {
        this.setState({ matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button-alert' });
    } else {
        console.log(this.props.parent);
        if (this.props.parent === 'Homepage') {
            console.log(this.props.history);
            this.props.history.push('/connexion');
        }
    }
}
```

Full file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Geosuggest from 'react-geosuggest';
import SearchBySubjectsModal from './modals/search_by_subjects_modal';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Search bar for parent to search for profs
 */
class SearchBar extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
        location: null,
        subjects: [],
        level: 'Collège',
        matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button',
        geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input'
    }

    this.onSuggestSelect = this.onSuggestSelect.bind(this);
    this.setSubjects = this.setSubjects.bind(this);
    this.search = this.search.bind(this);
}

/**
 * if the state for subjects and location is not null, then stop fields warning
 */
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.subjects.length > 0) {
        if (this.state.matieresButtonId !== 'matieres-button')
            this.setState({ matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button' });
    }
    if (this.state.location !== null) {
        if (this.state.geosuggestId !== 'geosuggest-input')
            this.setState({ geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input' });
    }
}

/**
 * set the state when choosing a location
 * @param {*} suggest 
 */
onSuggestSelect(suggest) {
    this.setState({ location: suggest });
}

/**
 * set the state when choosing subjects
 * @param {*} suggest 
 */
setSubjects(subjects, level) {
    this.setState({ subjects, level });
}

/**
 * Search method
 * Check if subjects or location are null (is so, show warnings)
 * If no warnings, perform search and redirect to search page
 * @param {*} event 
 */
search(event) {
    if (this.state.location === null) {
        this.setState({ geosuggestId: 'geosuggest-input-alert' });
    } else if (this.state.subjects.length === 0) {
        this.setState({ matieresButtonId: 'matieres-button-alert' });
    } else {
        console.log(this.props.parent);
        if (this.props.parent === 'Homepage') {
            console.log(this.props.history);
            this.props.history.push('/connexion');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Uses GeoSuggest (google places api) to choose a town
 * Uses Search By Subject modal to choose subjects
 */
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container" id="search-bar" >
            <div className="text-center">
                <form action="">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <Geosuggest
                                queryDelay={150}
                                autoActivateFirstSuggest={true}
                                inputClassName={this.state.geosuggestId}
                                placeholder="Où ?"
                                country="fr"
                                onSuggestSelect={this.onSuggestSelect} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <Link to="/">
                                <button data-toggle="modal" data-target=".choose-subject-modal" className="btn clickable" id={this.state.matieresButtonId}>
                                    <i className="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>  Matières ?
                                </button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <Link to="/">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn clickable" id="search-button" onClick={this.search}>
                                    <h5 id="search-btn-txt"><i className="fa fa-search"></i>  Trouver</h5>
                                </button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <SearchBySubjectsModal search={this.search} location={this.state.location} setSubjects={this.setSubjects} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
}





export default withRouter(SearchBar);
```

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Look for `this.props.router` I remember in newer versions of react the location was somewhere there.

Comment: why this.props.history ?

Comment: what version of `react-router`?

Comment: @GabrielFerreira to redirect using this.props.history.push('your/path')

Answer (score 0):

try use just: `hashHistory.push('/your/path');`

And in ur head: `import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';`

Comment: I would prefer to keep using BrowserRouter of react-router ;)

Comment: then use: `browserHistory.push('/your/path');`

Answer (score 0):

Your way is correct for react router v4. withRouter does expose the history object to the wrapped component. Just to make sure you create the history object and feed that to the router component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! What do you mean by "create the history object" ?

Comment: Using Browser Router or HashRouter, these two automatically creates the history object. if you are using plain Router need to pass the history props to the router like this <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>

Comment: Just read the above answer, you are using react router v2 so maybe using this browserHistory.push('/login') is valid in v2, v4 is totally updated version so you might need to update the react-router to use this.props.history